# How to get list of classes that declare an index with Tire?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I wrote following helper for `spec_helper`.

```
module TireHelper
  def clear_tire_index_for(*resources)
    resources.each do |res|
      res.index.delete
      res.tire.create_elasticsearch_index
      res.index.refresh
    end
  end
end
```

I would like to get a list of my `resources`.

I need that because I want clear all the tire indices before each spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Index Aliases API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-aliases.html):

```
aliases = Tire::Configuration.client.get(Tire::Configuration.url + '/_aliases').body
MultiJson.load(aliases).keys
=> ["index_1", "index_2", ...]
```

To delete all indices, just call:

```
RestClient.delete 'http://localhost:9200'
```

But be careful :)